# Determining if a collection has more than one max value

Tags: arrays, ruby

Right now I'm doing this, and it works:

```
groups = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
groups.select { |g| g.size == groups.max.size }.size
# => 1 # a clear majority

groups = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
groups.select { |g| g.size == groups.max.size }.size
# => 2 # needs to be passed to another filter
```

but I have a suspicion there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this snippet:

```
groups.group_by(&:size)[groups.max.size].size
```

Let me quickly explain what this does. I apologise in advance for the bad wording as "group" is a rather overloaded term here...

What it does, is first to group the arrays by size. This returns a hash:

```
groups = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
grouped = groups.group_by(&:size)
# => {3=>[[1, 1, 1]], 2=>[[2, 2]]}
```

Then, you take the array of group arrays containing exactly as many elements as the largest group

```
largest_list = grouped[groups.max.size]
# => [[2, 2]]
```

Now, you can simple get the size of this array to get the number of groups which have this length:

```
largest_list.size
# => 1
```

The reason why your approach is rather slow is that you calculate `groups.max.size` in your inner loop each time again.

Comment: that's a bit cleaner, thanks - and i renamed `groups` :D